# PowerShell Array ForEach not parsing correctly

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, split

I am writing a simple script to parse a couple of arrays (one nested inside the other) and then run a pen port check against each port and port type.

```
$ComputerList = 'dc-01'
$PortArray ='3389 TCP','389 TCP','53 UDP'

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
{
    foreach ($Port in $PortArray)
    {
        write-host $Port

        $PortPair = $port.split()
        if ($portpair[1] -eq 'TCP')
        {
            write-host $portpair[1]
        }
        elseif($portpair[1] -eq 'UDP')
        {
            write-host $portpair[1]
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Invalid protocol!"
        }          
    }
}
```

On my home PC, it parses the $PortArray fine, and then splits the 3389 and TCP parts separately into element 0 and element 1 . But when I run the same simple code on my work machine, it parses each character of each array element one at a time, so it fails the **If** check and I keep triggering the **Else** check.

Comment: Change `$port.Split()` to `$port.Split(" ")`

Comment: Powershell variables arent case-sensitive, but it's nicer not to mix as you do with $PortPair, $portpair.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I'll try that. I though with the Split method if you don't specify any parameters it splits on whitespace? Palle - agreed, but this was just a quick and dirty script :)

Comment: Ok, I've just changed it to Mathias' suggestion and it seems to make no difference. If I change the $PortArray to '1234 TCP','567 TCP','89 UDP', it's only returning the first two characters of each value (e.g. 1,2 and 5,6 and 8,9)

Comment: I got it working in the end using $PortNum,$PortProtocol = $port.split() . Not sure why referring to the $portpair[0] element style doesn't work...